# Press button in application using perl

Tags: perl, scripting, automation

How do I control an application using perl script. Once the application is opened, how can I press a button on the GUI of the application.
for eg:- after opening IDM, I want to add a new download. For doing that how do I press the "Add url button"

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what IDM is, you don't tell us this or what platform you're on. To automate applications on Windows use [Win32::GuiTest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aGuiTest), X11 -> [X11::GUITest](https://metacpan.org/pod/X11%3a%3aGUITest). The documentatoin for each links to pages explaing the theory, code samples and tutorials.